# Counting Organizations using Python and Sqlite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Counting Organizations

This application will read the mailbox data (mbox.txt) and count the number of email messages per organization (i.e. domain name of the email address) using a database with the following schema to maintain the counts.

CREATE TABLE Counts (org TEXT, count INTEGER)

When you have run the program on mbox.txt upload the resulting database file above for grading.

If you run the program multiple times in testing or with different files, make sure to empty out the data before each run.

You can use this code as a starting point for your application: http://www.py4e.com/code3/emaildb.py.

The data file for this application is the same as in previous assignments: http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt.

Because the sample code is using an UPDATE statement and committing the results to the database as each record is read in the loop, it might take as long as a few minutes to process all the data. The commit insists on completely writing all the data to disk every time it is called.

The program can be speed up greatly by moving the commit operation outside of the loop. In any database program, there is a balance between the number of operations you execute between commits and the importance of not losing the results of operations that have not yet been committed.

[The code I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14JAV.png)
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Cp5.png)

I have looked on other forums and scrapped the whole code and started over the bones of this is from the starting point in the above link.

I would appreciate any help this assignment is stressing me out I moved beyond it and finished others this is the last one in the class I need to complete.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, and not a screenshot.